# Vagrant provisioning - Puppet install php 5.6

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I am trying to install PHP 5.6 on my Vagrant CentOS 6.5 machine but it has been two days and I can't make Puppet install this specific PHP version. I did search SO and googled but could not find any solution that worked. Here are my experiments so far

```
yumrepo {
         "webtatic":
            descr          => "webtatic",
        baseurl            => "https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/webtatic-release.rpm",
            failovermethod => "priority",
            gpgcheck       => "0",
            enabled        => "1";
          } 



yumrepo {
         "webtatic":
            descr          => "epel-release",
        baseurl            => "https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/epel-release.rpm",
            failovermethod => "priority",
            gpgcheck       => "0",
            enabled        => "1";
          } 



package { 'php56w' :
  ensure => 'present'
}
```

Throughout my experiments I've been getting different error messages when provisioning:

```
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Package[php56w]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install php56w' returned 1: Error: Nothing to do
```

or

```
==> default: Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install php56w' returned 1: Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel-release. Please verify its path and try again
```

I also tried to use [example42/php](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/example42/php) module

```
class { 'php':
  version => '5.6.10',
}
```

gives me

```
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Php/Package[php]/ensure: change from absent to 5.6.10 failed: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install php-5.6.10' returned 1: Error: Nothing to do
==> default:
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/File[php.conf]: Dependency Package[php] has failures: true
```

What is the proper way to install specific php version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : Giving another look, it seems the repo is not correct.

1. it uses the mirror repo with rpm full link, this is not necessary, I am not a `yum` expert in any way but I review my repo file and they dont have the link to rpm file, so I have changed to the *uk.repo.webtatic.com*
2. just to be safe, make a require on the install yum repo when running the install of php so you're sure it will pull from the additional repo

my puppet file looks like

```
class repo {
  yumrepo { "webtatic":
    descr          => "epel-release",
    baseurl        => "https://uk.repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/$architecture",
    failovermethod => "priority",
    gpgcheck       => "0",
    enabled        => "1";
  } 
}

class php {
  package { "php56w": 
    ensure  => installed, 
    require => Yumrepo["webtatic"] }
}

include repo
include php
```

and php 5.6.12 get installed in this case:

```
fhenri@machine:/Volumes/WORK/project/phpbox$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Thu Aug 27 08:18:26 2015 from 172.16.42.1
Welcome to your Packer-built virtual machine.
[ariba@localhost ~]$ php -version
PHP 5.6.12 (cli) (built: Aug  9 2015 11:16:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

**OLD ANSWER :** why not using an existing module ?

For my case I use the https://forge.puppetlabs.com/example42/php/readme module, it allows you to specify the php version :

```
class { 'php':
  version => '5.6.10',
}
```

it should work

Comment: I also tried it and unfortunately it does not work. I updated my question with error messages. I believe it assumes you have correct repo in the package manager, and it appends version to "php-". So requiring 5.6 would do yum install php-5.6

Comment: making an update of the answer as it seems the repo used was incorrect, suggesting another one, works for me

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! Works like a charm, and I really like the require => Yumrepo["webtatic"] bit :-)